# Placing a While-loop Inside a Function

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop

I am new to programming and want to place a while-loop inside function so I can call the function. Below is the code I have written. The loop itself works fine, but the list 'numbers' never gets appended when I try putting it in a function.

```
numbers = []

def loop_function(numbers):
    x = 6
    i = 0
    while i < x:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d\n" % i

    return numbers

print "The numbers: " 

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have function definition, and no call of it

```
numbers = []

def loop_function(numbers):
    x = 6
    i = 0
    while i < x:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d\n" % i

    return numbers

loop_function(numbers)
print "The numbers: " 

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

but this still isn't good piece of code

edit:
what would you say if your function looks like this?

```
def loop_function(num):
    num.extend(range(6))
```

Comment: okay, to print the function I would need to add a line of code that has: print loop_function()?

Comment: that do you mean "print the function". to print value that function return?  
yes.  
but you are using the same name for global variable and local variable, which is passed by reference so its the same variable. not goot idea.
pick another name for variable in function

Comment: Oh! So, I added that line of code and put 'numbers' parentheses and it ran!

Comment: I changed the local variable to 'list'. Does that make it a better piece of code?

Comment: list is a keyword :P very bad idea :P  
what would you say to name "num" or "nums"?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'll remember to not use keywords as variable names.